# Should I use "have" or "had" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> She stared at me with eyes that seemed to **had/have** found something
>   they had once deemed as unreal.

What's the correct option and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the construction *seem to VERB*, the *to* is an infinitive marker and *VERB* must be in its infinitive form. In your sentence, consequently, you must use the infinitive form of the verb *HAVE*, which is *have*.